# IE7 fails to load page with jQuery .load command

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to load a div into my page (it is an iteration through a series of classes) using jQuery's .load command. It works fine in Safari, Crome, and firefox but not IE (7 i don't care about 6 and I don't have 8 to test). I have checked and cannot find any mismatched tags as suggested previously here, I have also tried appending a random number to the end of the url to prevent IE caching the code, when that did not work I removed it to prevent future problems. I have tried just loading the basic page without passing the div class to see if parsing it was the problem, but that didn't make a difference. I know the code runs, as it gives me a response from the function both before and after the .load command.

Here's the code:

```
function desc(){
        $(".description").each(function(i){
            url = $(this).attr("meta");
            $(this).load(url+' .ProductWarrantyContainer');
        });
    }
```

I have several functions that are having this problem but all are based of this one and only slight variants.

Here is the page if it helps anyone to see the original page [Brain Wellness pro](http://www.brainwellnesspro.com/brands/Neurogistics.html)

I'm going to keep looking but any help the Stack Overflow community could provide would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:
On further exploration it seems that it does run and does load the full page but does not seem to be able to parse the html for the div I need, or put it into the div it is assigned... any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the code you used for caching?

Comment: @Fred - the code i used was [+  Math.random()*99999] added to line 3

Comment: Yup, this is what I saw on another SO post. Oh well, I can't help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, After discovering that the .load() function was working i striped the html down to the basics and my div. It turns out this was an error generated by something being mismatched in some part of my code. I will check more thoroughly next time before posting. And to anyone else posting here regarding this question, always check your code!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting some error here both ie8 and 7 , please fix this , this can have cascading effect , there are other errors on the page too.

**line 110
Expected identifier , string or number**

```
function quickLoad(url){
            var cssObj = {
                'display': '',
                'z-index': '3000',
                'opacity':' 0.5',
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'postion': 'relative',
                **'top': '0px;',** // please remove cama here
            };
            $('#ModalContent').load(url+' #quickLookData');
            $('#qlMore').attr('href', url);
            $('#backgroundCover').fadeIn(300);
            $('#ModalContainer').fadeIn(300);
        };
```

Comment: You should mention, at least, that this is caused by the trailing comma in the `cssObj` Object, which IE chokes on. Just dumping the error here and telling the OP to 'please fix this' probably won't help him much.

Comment: @YI sure, will do that from next time, do you want me to remove this as answer??let me know i can delete it if this doesn't give user a direction to fix the problem

Comment: This whole function was irrelevant i was just leaving it in incase i found a use for it latter, i removed it and the .load() function still does not work. Thanks though i didn't realize it was causing a problem.